# SQLite injection - Doing something wrong with querying

Tags: android, sqlite, mono, sql-injection, sqlite-net

I'm trying to do some `Sqlite` querying but I don't know if I'm doing it correctly because this feels really unsave to do. So my question is how do I fix this. I'm new to the whole `Xamarin` and `Sqlite` usage.

I'm only making a `Android` project so it is not a cross platform application. I also cant seem to figure out where to get `Mono.Data.Sqlite` if I even need it. Everything is welcome.

```
   static public List<Users> SelectUser(string name)
        {
            try
            {
                var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(DatabasePath);
                {
                    return dbConn.Query<Users>("SELECT name, email FROM TblUsers where name = " + name+ ";");        
                }
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: so, what is the problem? r u getting an exception? it just doesnt look nice?(unsave you say?). I think you are missing some single quotes around the name `"SELECT name, email FROM TblUsers where name = '" + name+ "';"`

Comment: Look up *Prepared Statements*. That will make it much easier and more secure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **Prepared Statements**.
There is an official java documentation about Prepared Statements from Oracle [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

You can also search it on google. There are a lot of guides on how to use prepared statements.